# Vue Route param not change when Vuex state changed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I need to create a link which will go to current logged in user's profile page, like this:

```
<a :to="{name: 'EditUser', params: {id: user.id}}">Profile</a>
```

with `user` is a vuex module. But the `user.id` not reactivity when the vuex state changed, although all other elements changed. Example:

```
<div>{{ user.name }}</div>
```

or

```
<div>{{ user.email }}</div>
```

Please help me to trouble this. Thank all!

Comment: Try adding `:key="user.id"`

Comment: @Phil where to add? sorry cause I'm newbie in Vue and JS

Comment: On your `<a>` tag

Comment: But I'm not rendering the loop

Comment: What's your point? The `:key` binding isn't just for loops

Comment: @Phil: the `user.id` was reactivity, but the console show: `[vue-router] missing param for named route "EditUser": Expected "id" to be defined`. What's wrong here?